# pymongo as_class and son manipulation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I have a very special question about son manipulation and the `as_class` parameter by **`find`**.
After I add the AutoReference manipulator I get a SON object from the curser and not a object from the class which I defined in the `as_class` parameter.

Is there someone with the same problem, is this a bug in pymongo or I am only stupid?

Best regardes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently son_manipulators always return instances of SON. If you need to use as_class you will need to handle DBRef in your client.